# PHP checkboxes for questions

Tags: php, database

I'm having trouble understanding the logic behind a survey style script i'm working on.

I've written the first part where I pull the question and answer from the db but I can't figure out how I can create a multiple choice for each question whilst in the while loop and then store the value the user has selected. My brain is fried trying to figure it out :(

first part of my code is straight forward I think:

```
<?php
//retreive questions from database and put into question box

$query = "SELECT `Question`, `Answer` FROM `questions`";

$question = mysql_query($query);

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($question)){
?>
<div id="ContainerQuestion">
    <span style="Question">Question <?php echo $row['Question']; ?></span>
// Have A,B,C,D outputted as values in a checkbox and then the text after????
</div>
<?php
}

?>
```

I'd really appreciate any help.

Comment: It may not help answer your question, but you should stop using `mysql_*` functions. They're being deprecated. Instead use [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) (supported as of PHP 5.1) or [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) (supported as of PHP 4.1). If you're not sure which one to use, [read this article](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/pdo-vs-mysqli-which-should-you-use/).

Comment: you need to restructure the database to achieve such a aim.

Comment: database is mapped out:  QuestionId Question Answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you mean this?

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($question)){
?>
<div name="ContainerQuestion">
    <span style="Question">Question <?php echo $row['Question']; ?></span><br />
    <input type="checkbox" name="question_<?= $row['Question_ID']; ?>[]" value="A" <?= $row['Answer'] == 'A' ? 'checked="checked"' : '' ?> /> A<br />
    <input type="checkbox" name="question_<?= $row['Question_ID']; ?>[]" value="B" <?= $row['Answer'] == 'B' ? 'checked="checked"' : '' ?>/> B<br />
    <input type="checkbox" name="question_<?= $row['Question_ID']; ?>[]" value="C" <?= $row['Answer'] == 'C' ? 'checked="checked"' : '' ?>/> C<br />
    <input type="checkbox" name="question_<?= $row['Question_ID']; ?>[]" value="D" <?= $row['Answer'] == 'D' ? 'checked="checked"' : '' ?>/> D<br />
// Have A,B,C,D outputted as values in a checkbox and then the text after????
</div>
<?php
}
```

**NOTE:** You shouldn't give the `<div>` a static (read: non-unique) ID within the loop - HTML rules state that IDs must be unique.

Also, if the user may only select one option, you may want to use radio buttons instead.

Comment: how can i "non" static the div as this is the way I learnt how to do this style of code?

Comment: Add a variable that increments with each loop. Don't just give the `<div>` an id of "ContainerQuestion". Append something that changes each time.

Comment: so something like ContainerQuestion.$randomString?

Comment: Or the ID of the question that's being written. I wouldn't do a "random" string because of the possibility of overlap.

Answer (score 0):

```
$opts = array(
  'a' => 'foo',
  'b' => 'bar',
  'c' => 'baz',
  'd' => 'all of the above'
);

foreach($opts as $key => $val) {
    echo <<<EOL
<input type="checkbox" name="something" value="{$key}" /> {$val}<br />

EOL:
}
```